# My class has an __init__ function that class a method that is never executed throws exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class HomeworkHelper:
    "This is a HomeworkHelper"
    def homeworkClassSelection(self, customerClass):
        if customerClass == "SC":
            return "SENIOR"
        if customerClass == "TD" or customerClass == "TA":
            return "TEACHER ASSISTANCE"
        if customerClass == "PD" or customerClass == "PA" :
            return "PROFESSOR"
            
    def __init__(self, id=0, firstName="", lastName="", expirationDate="", addressLine1="", addressLine2="", city="", state="", zip="", dateOfBirth="", customerClass=""):
        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.expirationDate = expirationDate
        self.addressLine1 = addressLine1
        self.addressLine2 = addressLine2
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zip = zip
        self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        self.customerClass = homeworkClassSelection(customerClass) # this line throws exception says that it can't find homeworkClassSelection
```

Using Python 3.9.4 64 bit
VSCode on Mac

```
NameError: name 'homeworkClassSelection' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *self.* When you call class methods:

```py
self.homeworkClassSelection(customerClass)
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: `homeworkClassSelection` seems to be an instance method. Your solution still applies though (for instance methods _and_ if it were decorated with `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`).